# Subreport fails to pull data

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I have three tables: A, B, and C. A has equipment information where column1 is the primary key. C has parts listed with their details and corresponding part ID's as the primary key in column1. B saves the selected PK ID from `C.column1` with the corresponding PK from `A.column1` to link parts with their equipment.

I'm making a report where the equipment in A is listed, with a subreport for all the parts linked to each equipment from C.

My dataset1 has 2 tableAdaptors pulled from MySQL - one lists the equipment and the other lists the parts. If I preview both tableAdaptors, I get the information I want. (I use one dataset for the info as it is linked to one report.) My data on the main report is pulling through to list the equipment, but my sub report is empty. How do I get my sub report to show the data?

I have setup a link where the PK from A links to the PK of C. The configure part (Subreport Links) of the reports where you setup links, does pick up the relations between the 3 tables. The sub report just doesn't pull data when I run the report.

Added Info (sorry for the late response, has randsomeware to deal with, lol):

Here is my DataSet Currently, I did have the two tables split with a TableAdaptor for each, then merge it into one to see if it will make a difference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFpeo.jpg)

Here us what my main report looks like, you can see where the sub report is added (underlined the name in red):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKEwC.jpg)

This is my current code loaded on the "click" function of a button:

```
//Create SQL connection
        SqlConnection SQLConnect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand SQLEquipLinkedReport = SQLConnect.CreateCommand();
        SQLEquipLinkedReport.CommandText = "EXECUTE EquipmentListDataSet";

        try
        {
            //Pull info from DB
            SQLConnect.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter myEquipLinkedDA = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLEquipLinkedReport);
            EquipmentListDataSet EquipLinkedDS = new EquipmentListDataSet();
            //Dump info in DataSet
            myEquipLinkedDA.Fill(EquipLinkedDS, "EquipmentListDataSet");
            SQLConnect.Close();
            //Call report and fill it with the DB info
            EquipmentLinkedDetails myEquipRPT = new EquipmentLinkedDetails();
            myEquipRPT.SetDataSource(EquipLinkedDS);
            ReportViewerLinkedParts.ReportSource = myEquipRPT;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: where did you place the sub report and what fields have you linked from main report and sub report and also what is your main report design?

Comment: Where is your query came from, Code behind or in crystal report itself?>

Comment: Ok I have managed to sort out my problem, it was the way DataSet was linked on the reports.
Now I have one last question. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with Crystal Reports installed for it. 
How do I get the first page header to repeat on all the pages? It does not have "header properties" when I right click in the header or "RepeatOnNewPage".